# Sliding panels - one works, the others don't

Tags: c#, winforms

I've run into a bit of a wall and I don't know how I've managed to stuff it up. I'm trying to have multiple panels on my application in C# and each slides in and out from the menu along the side. I've written a separate slide class:

```
class Slide
{
    Panel pane;
    Button btn;
    bool hidden;
    Timer t;
    const int maxWidth = 315;

    public Slide(Panel p, Button b)
    {
        this.pane = p;
        this.btn = b;
        hidden = true;

        btn.Click += new EventHandler(btnClick);

        t = new Timer();
        t.Interval = 15;
        t.Tick += new EventHandler(timeTick);
    }

    private void timeTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(hidden)
        {
            SlidingPane(+10);
        }
        else
        {
            SlidingPane(-10);
        }
    }

    private void btnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        t.Start();
    }

    private void SlidingPane(int i)
    {
        pane.Width += i;

        if(pane.Width >= maxWidth || pane.Width <= 0)
        {
            t.Stop();
            hidden = !hidden;
        }
    }
}
```

And I've initialised the panels as follows:

```
    Slide menuP, calendarP, peopleP, taskP, settingsP;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ButtonColours();
        InitialisePanes();
    }

    private void InitialisePanes()
    {
        menuP = new Slide(menuPane, menuButton);
        calendarP = new Slide(calendarPane, calendarButton);
        peopleP = new Slide(peoplePane, peopleButton);
        taskP = new Slide(taskPane, toDoButton);
        settingsP = new Slide(settingsPane, settingsButton);
    }
```

And here's the Form designer code for the working panel:

```
this.menuPane.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateGray;
this.menuPane.Controls.Add(this.peoplePane);
this.menuPane.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
this.menuPane.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 0);
this.menuPane.Name = "menuPane";
this.menuPane.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 652);
this.menuPane.TabIndex = 2;
```

And the others are exactly the same. Eg:

```
this.peoplePane.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.SlateGray;
this.peoplePane.Controls.Add(this.calendarPane);
this.peoplePane.Dock = System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle.Left;
this.peoplePane.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(67, 0);
this.peoplePane.Name = "peoplePane";
this.peoplePane.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(0, 652);
this.peoplePane.TabIndex = 2;
```

I've started up my application and I click on the menuButton, it works. Slides in and out beautifully. I click on the others and....nothing happens.

Can anyone see why this is happening? Everything I'm looking at tells me that it should be working.

Comment: Just a side note: you don't need to provide your constructor arguments by `ref` in this case. Just remove `ref` everywhere in this code.

Comment: Thanks dymanoid, done so :)

Comment: They all sit at the same spot on purpose?

Comment: They're like menu panels that slide in and out, kind of similar to skype

Comment: Are you sure about the nesting? You are nesting peoplePane in menuPane (menuPane.Controls.Add(this.peoplePane);)  and then calendarPane in peoplePane (peoplePane.Controls.Add(this.calendarPane);) - This means that the calendarPane  can only show when peoplePane shows etc..!

Comment: @TaW Changing this seems to have no effect on the problem. I took out all the this.pane.Controls.Add(this.pane) lines and ran it...still only the menupane is sliding.

Comment: Are the others all showing? Can you post an image of what it looks like? the sliding works fine here for any number of panes.

Comment: https://i.postimg.cc/MTwYBJzF/image.png That's the menu panel open, but the others don't open at all.

Comment: OK, but the main question remains: are the other nested in the 1st one or not? To test insert a `Console.Writeline("peoplePane.Parent: " + peoplePane.Parent.Name);` etc.. The nesting can happen easily when moving panels to the same location. To avoid either use code or the keyboard, not the mouse!

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Answer (score 0):

To make sure all panes are correctly **aligned** with each other and **(not) nested** you could use code like this:

```
foreach( Control ctl in new[]  { peoplePane, calendarPane, taskPane, settingsPane })
{
    ctl.Parent = menuPane.Parent;
    ctl.Location = menuPane.Location;
}
```

It assumes that `menuPane` is at the right spot and makes all others sit right on top without nesting them.

The code you posted contained incorrect nesting and moving panels to the same spot with the **mouse** will also create (in this case unwanted) nesting. Moving with the **keyboard** avoids it but is tedious.